# Что делает этот код? [ООП Python]

Tags: python, ооп, функции

Недавно перебрался к ООП, не могу понять что выполняет данный код. Нашёл в видео, а автор не объясняет.

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age, bread):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.bread = breed

    def bark(self):
        print("Bark")

    def getInfo(self):
        return {name: self.name,
                age: self.age,
                breed: self.breed}
```

Comment: Фигню какую то делает этот код. Это и то с учётом что этот скрипт не полный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь не хватает строчки создания самого класса.
Например, `class Dog:`

А так - это код класса собаки.

3 метода:

1. Инициация объекта класса (конструктор)
   Задает экземпляру класса (конкретной собаке) свойства: имя, возраст, порода
2. Гавкать (выводит текст "Bark")
3. Получить информацию об объекте класса:
   Возвращает словарь: {имя:имя этой собаки, возраст: возраст этой собаки, порода: порода этой собаки}

Comment: подправил вопрос, автор промахнулся с блоком кода. Сейчас все нормально отображается